# Applying margin-bottom to an element

Tags: html, css, margin

I tried positioning a div element using margin-bottom. For some reason the margin-bottom doesn't appear to affect the position of the element. I tried searching for an answer, though all answers had something to do with `position:absolute`, and I still couldn't get it to work.

However, I did manage to position it using a negative margin-top, but I'm still curious to know what causes it not to work.

Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btadB/3/) showing the HTML/CSS.
(what I'm talking about is the image. The margin-bottom is set to 100px.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with what will hopefully explain why margin-bottom doesn't affect the position of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the position absolute property in the DIV with the class "productImage". Like this, for example:

```
.productImage {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Using this i've manipulated the image sucessfully. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

A margin on the bottom would only work if the element was positioned via bottom somehow. Right now, it's positioned based on its top and that is being set by the H1. If you don't want the H1 to be a block, set it to `display:inline-block`. You could also set the width to be that of the paragraph.

As you noted, this is why a negative margin-top works.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- Negative (or simply smaller) `margin-top`
- `position: relative` and a negative `top`

Further explanation:

margin-bottom, in normal document flow, will only affect the position of elements that come after it, due to the fact that normal block-level elements will expand their height with the height of their children. Thus, the position of your element is determined by the elements before it, as well as its own margin-top.